# How to stop the default email notifications for a particular User in salesforce through apex code

Tags: apex, community, chatter

I am trying to stop the default email notifications for a particular User in salesforce through apex code.
Stopping default email notifications can be done manually by going to My Settings -> Email Settings and unchecking 'Receive emails' checkbox.
I need to achieve the same thing through Apex code. Please suggest how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the settings on the NetworkMember object? For Communities, this seems to take precedence. For a similar issue, I poked it via the developer console with this query:

```
SELECT Id, PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail FROM NetworkMember WHERE MemberId = ''
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to the chatter email settings feature:

[image]

You can clear this checkbox by setting the UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail field to true for the user.  In the screenshot above my Receive emails checkbox is set, but if I execute the following Apex code:

```
User u=[select id, UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail from User 
      where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
u.UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail=true;
update u;
```

the checkbox is cleared:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am trying to disable all the email notifications to a Community User. Not only chatter email notifications, but i need to disable notifications for Private messages too. I have tried the above code which you have given but still it is triggering Private message notification email.

Comment: It looks like the private message email notifications are controlled by the UserPreferencesDisableMessageEmail property on the User sObject.

Comment: I have set 'UserPreferencesDisableMessageEmail' property to true. Even now the private message email notifications are getting triggered.

Comment: Wonder where we can find the full list of which API name corresponds to what.. eg. UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail to toggle the "Receive emails" .. how about <apiname> to toggle the "Mentions me in a post"

Answer (score 0):

Run below code in developer console to disable chatter only for community users.

```
Profile p = [Select Id,name from Profile where name = 'System Administrator']; 
List<NetworkMember> nmList = [Select Id,MemberId,NetworkId,PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail FROM NetworkMember WHERE Member.ProfileId != p.Id];
    for(NetworkMember nm: netMemList){
     nm.PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail = true;   
    }
    update nmList;
```